# The MySQL query only matches if begins with integer

Tags: mysql

The query:

```
SELECT  a.*, b.* FROM `links` a, `product` b WHERE a.title LIKE CONCAT('%',b.supplier_name,'%') AND b.supplier_name!='' AND b.supplier_name!=0 ;
```

It comes up with matches only if the supplier_name begins with 0-9. For example, '2020103' is matches whereas 'U13002L1' is not.

Where did I go wrong in this query?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: How do you expect `b.supplier_name!=0` to work?

Comment: I think, because you have !=0, it is maybe trying to see the column as an integer. Maybe try replacing !=0 by !='0'.

Comment: @Uueerdo some of the supplier names are blank or 0, I don't need those to be matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing character type to integer type, MySQL does an implicit cast of the character to a numeric value. MySQL has very lenient rules.

```
b.supplier_name != 0
```

is equivalent to

```
( b.supplier_name + 0 ) != 0
```

---

As a demonstration of the implicit cast behavior, consider:

```
SELECT '1ABC' + 0 
     , '023X' + 0 
     , 'fi5'  + 0
```

---

To get character comparison, compare to a *string* literal rather than a numeric literal, e.g.

```
AND b.supplier_name != '0'
```